# Amazon EC2 cannot access services running on ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to expose a node server that is running on `port 80`.

I have added a security group which can be seen in the `security tab` of the instance.

[image]

I have checked the `Internet Gateway` which is attached

[image]

And it is set as a `target` in my

[image]

Everything appears to be fine inside the box but I cannot reach the node server via the internet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it in public subnet? Dues it have public IP? Are you using custom or default VPC?

Comment: Probably you are not running your server on that particular port.try accessing your server by the IP:8080 if you can then everything is fine just have to run your server on port 80

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the EC2 (node server) and make sure a process is listening on port 80.
    `netstat -tnlp | grep 80`
2. Make sure no firewall is blocking the port. Since there is no basic environment information, e.g. OS (windows? Linux? Ubuntu? CentOS? etc etc), I cannot suggest any.
3. Make sure the process responds.  `telnet <public IP of EC2> 80`.
4. Make sure another EC2 in the VPC can connect to the process running on port 80. `curl <public ip of target EC2>`

Comment: Hi Mon,

Thanks for your comment.

So the output from netstat inside the instance is:
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      19858/docker-proxy

Telnet command outside of the box does not connect

Comment: As there is no "80" being reported form netstat, no process is running on 80. As port 8080 is reported, my guess is the process (web server?) is actually running on 8080. Please make sure you run a server to run on port 80. As port 80 (< 1024) is privileged port, the process needs the permission to access the port (e.g. root).